# Не работает Leaderboard android play game. В первый раз заходит и показывает таблицу, но после после набора очков возникает ошибка

Tags: java, android, google-play, leaderboard

Подключил к своему приложению leaderboard. Сгенерировал apk, установил вручную – вроде все нормально работает. Выложил в play market. Скачал и установил оттуда, теперь в первый раз заходит и показывает таблицу, но стоит набрать хоть одно очко, выдает ошибку и больше не работает. В чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы хоть код показали и логи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем решил сам.
Нужно в Google API Console https://console.developers.google.com удалить OAuth ключи. И создать их заново, только не вручную, а из Google Play Console https://developer.android.com/distribute/console?hl=ru. Зайти в Игровые сервисы, связать заново приложение. Связать нужно три раза одно приложение – с debug SHA1 ключом, с release SHA1 ключом и с собственным ключом подписи google (он находится в Управление релизом -> Подписание приложений).